# Can I say: where is he go to college?

Tags: tense

Is it possible to say 'where is he go to college' instead of 'where did he go to college'?

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Sometimes I hear people say the first sentence although the mean the second one.  But sounds wrong...

Comment: No, you don't. You hear *Where **does** he go to college?*, but people often append the beginning /d/ phoneme to the previous word (or elide it entirely or some such), so you end up hearing something akin to *Where(d) uz he go to college?*, which you misinterpret as you've shown. As written, your first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a misheard sentence.

Comment: I agree with userr2864291.  You misheard "Where **does** he go to college?** using the simple present tense, or possibly "Where **is he going** to college?" using the present progressive.  "Where is he go" is not grammatical.

Comment: Didn't see this conversation until after I posted an answer to this. My bad. Agree with Andrew and userr2684291.

Answer (score 1):

*The use of 'is' should be reserved for when it's the present tense* i.e. Where is he going to college? (implying you believe he's still attending college and hasn't graduated). Alternatively, you could say Where does he go to college.

*The use of 'Did' is for, when you believe the college attending happened in the past* i.e. Where did he go to college?